# Round up or round down number to nearest hundred in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to round up and round down certain number to the nearest hundred

for example

1. 17100 (round up) -> return 17100
2. 20920 (round down) -> return 20900
3. 20520 (round up) -> return 20600

Comment: What is the criteria to choose which one to round up or round down. Or you just need two function to round up and round down?

Comment: You can do something like : `20920.toStringAsFixed(-2) as int;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. Use `ceil` to round up, and `floor` to round down:

```dart
void main() {
  print((17100 / 100).ceil() * 100);
  print((20920 / 100).floor() * 100);
  print((20520 / 100).ceil() * 100);
}
```